# GNS3: performance tests using iperf3?

Tags: bandwidth, testing, performance, iperf

I'm running some performance tests on GNS3 (I know I shouldn't, but it is not until Friday that I will have the college lab available), and I'm trying to compare real BW or "speed" and theoritecal.

So if I just put the command : "show interfaces serial1/1"

**Do I get the "theoretical" value of the link?**

(MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1544 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec)

So when I run iperf from my loopback interface (PC1) (client side) to my Linux VM (server side) I get and average of **BW= 1.1 Mbps.**

Is is safe to say that the performance of the link is:

**Performance = real BW / theoritecal BW = 71.24 %**

This is the topology I use, and it goes from PC1 to PC2:

[image]

I expect the performance to be higher in a real environment since GNS3 emulates everything and it consumes too much.

This is my real PC specs:
Intel i5 processor
8 GB of RAM

Thanks in advance! :)

Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't trust GNS3 for throughput tests. As soon as you use a router in your topology you are likely only to get 5mb/sec tops, regardless of whether you use a serial, ethernet or fast ethernet interface and regardless of how powerful your PC is. (Note that the performance hit won't be seen if you use a GNS3 switch instead of a router, however, the switches are extremely limited in what they can do).

A few years ago GNS3's website used to say something along the lines of *don't use GNS3 for production workloads as GNS3 routers perform more than 1,000 times slower than the real thing.* I know you're only labbing, but the reason why I mention this is that the devs themselves say its performance is not even close to what you will get from real equipment.

Finally, just an FYI - A little while back I did a few iperf tests through a couple of VMs connected to GNS3 on my i7 with 32GB of RAM (see [this page](http://www.oznetnerd.com/2012/12/01/new-pc-nexus-1000v-come/) for specs, though at the time of writing I only had 16GB of RAM). If I recall correctly I only got about 3mb/sec. However, when I [rejigged the lab](http://www.oznetnerd.com/2015/01/31/guide-building-self-contained-virtual-steelhead-lab-part-1/) to include a couple of Riverbed Steelheads I saw a massive improvements, but that's a whole other story :)

To sum up the above - GNS3 is great for testing protocols, configs, etc but is pretty much useless when testing throughput.

Comment: No worries at all, it's my pleasure.

Comment: GNS3 developer here. I confirm the answer we can't get reliable performances it's depend of a lot of factors. The images from constructor are sometimes rate limited in virtualized environments for example.